# Input a tex file in my document, but it's not placed well

Tags: tables, input

Recently, I input a `.tex` file (just name it as `table1.tex`, which contains a table I needed in my paper) in my main document, but it's not  placed well, I want it be in the middle, but it's on  the left, how should I do it?

`table1.tex`

```
\newsavebox\independent
\begin{lrbox}{\independent}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
 P_f &= (\sum_{i=1}^{n}  P_i^{-1})^{-1} \\
  \hat{x}_f &= P_f (\sum_{i=1}^{n} P_i^{-1} \hat{x}_i)
\end{align*} 
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}

 \newsavebox\correlated
\begin{lrbox}{\correlated}
\begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
\begin{align*}
 P_f &= (e^T \Sigma^{-1} e)^{-1} \\
  \hat{x}_f &= P_f (e^T \Sigma^{-1} \hat{x})
 \end{align*} 
\end{minipage}
 \end{lrbox}
  \newsavebox\uc
  \begin{lrbox}{\uc}
  \begin{minipage}{0.3\textwidth}
  \begin{align*}
  P_f &= (\sum_{i=1}^{n}  \omega_i P_i^{-1})^{-1} \\
  \hat{x}_f &= P_f (\sum_{i=1}^{n} \omega_i P_i^{-1} \hat{x}_i)
\end{align*}  
\end{minipage}   
\end{lrbox}
\begin{table}
 \caption{Multi-sensor Fusion Rules}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{center}
 \begin{tabular}{ccc}
  Types of Estimation Errors & Fusion Rules & Comments \\ \hline \hline
    \makecell{No Correlations \\(Independent)} & \usebox{\independent} & Optimal \\
  \hline
\makecell{Known Correlations \\   (Correlated)} & \usebox{\correlated} \tnote{*} & Optimal \\ \hline
  Unknown Correlations & \usebox{\uc} \tnote{**} &  \makecell{Suboptimal }\\ \hline \hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tablenotes}
\item[*]  $e=[I, \cdots, I]^T$, $\Sigma=(P_{ij}), \; i,j=1,\cdots, n$, and $\hat{x}=   [\hat{x}_1^T, \cdots, \hat{x}_n^T]^T$. 
\item[**] Covariance intersection rule, where $\omega_i\in [0\,,1],\; \sum_{i=1}^n  \omega_i=1$, and $\omega_i=\arg\min_{\omega_i\in[0\,,1]} \text{tr}\{P_{f}\}$.
\end{tablenotes}
\end{center}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}
```

`Main code`:

```
\documentclass[preview]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
\usepackage{makecell}
\begin{document}
   \input{table1}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Just remove the instructions `\begin{center}` and `\end{center}` and insert the instruction `\centering` *before* (not after) `\begin{threeparttable}`.

Comment: It works, thank you. Why \centering has such an amazing magic?

Comment: Instead of centering the contents inside threeparttable, you have to center the threeparttable itself. That's what it did.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks for you insightful comment.

Comment: BTW, there are only 256 box registers and you are using them up at an alarming rate.  You might consider putting the whole file inside a \bgroup \egroup and using \let\independent=\box0, etc.

Comment: @JohnKormylo I  donot understand what you mean, would you give me an example, that would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @JohnKormylo As long as e-TeX is around, then there are nominally more that 256 boxes to be used since e-TeX increases these to 32768 boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used  the `caption` package, for a correct vertical spacing between caption and table.

I took the opportunity to improve you table, not using `minipage`s, and replacing the `\hline` commands with commands from `booktabs`:

*Table1.tex:*

```
%to be input
\newsavebox\independent
\begin{lrbox}{\independent}
  $ \begin{aligned}
  P_f &= \Bigl(∑_{i=1}ⁿ P_i⁻¹\Bigr)⁻¹ \\
  \hat{x}_f &= P_f \Bigl (∑_{i=1}ⁿ P_i⁻¹ \hat{x}_i\Bigr)
  \end{aligned}
  $
\end{lrbox}

\newsavebox\correlated
\begin{lrbox}{\correlated}
  $ \begin{aligned}
  P_f &= (e^T Σ^{-1} e)⁻¹ \\
  \hat{x}_f &= P_f (e^T Σ^{-1} \hat{x})
  \end{aligned}
  $
\end{lrbox}
\newsavebox\uc
\begin{lrbox}{\uc}
  $ \begin{aligned}
  P_f &= \Bigl(∑_{i=1}ⁿ ω_i P_i⁻¹\Bigr)⁻¹ \\
  \hat{x}_f &= P_f \Bigl (∑_{i=1}ⁿ ω_i P_i⁻¹ \hat{x}_i\Bigr)
  \end{aligned} $
\end{lrbox}


  \setlength\aboverulesep{0.65ex}
  \setlength\belowrulesep{0.9ex}
  \captionsetup{position =above}

  \caption{Multi-sensor Fusion Rules}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{cc@{\qquad}c}
      Types of Estimation Errors & Fusion Rules & Comments \\
      \midrule\midrule
      \makecell{No Correlations \\(Independent)} & \usebox{\independent} & Optimal \\
      \cmidrule(l r){1-3}
      \makecell{Known Correlations \\ (Correlated)} & \usebox{\correlated} \tnote{*} & Optimal \\
      \cmidrule(l r){1-3}
      Unknown Correlations & \usebox{\uc} \tnote{**} & \makecell{Suboptimal } \\
      \midrule\midrule
    \end{tabular}
    \vskip 0.8ex
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item[*] $e=[I, ⋯ , I]^T$, $\Sigma=(P_{ij}), \; i,j=1, ⋯ , n$, and $\hat{x}= [\hat{x}_1^T, ⋯ , \hat{x}_n^T]^T$.\vskip 1.2ex
      \item[**] Covariance intersection rule, where $ω_i ∈ [0\,,1],\; ∑_{i=1}^n ω_i=1$, and $ω_i=\arg\min_{ω_i\in[0\,,1]} \text{tr}\{P_{f}\}$.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}

\endinput
```

*Main file:*

```
 \documentclass[preview]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}%
\usepackage{makecell, caption, booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
    \input{table1inputvar}
\end{table}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you maybe want to replace `Σ`, `ω`, `ⁿ`, etc with TeX macros?

Comment: Sure. It' my my editor's fault again! :o(

Comment: You solution looks good, thanks for your efforts. However, can your explain to me that  why 1) not use table environment, and 2) replace the caption command with captionof{table}? 3) not using minipages, and replacing the \hline commands with commands from booktabs? Since it's my habit write such codes, it's better to know the pros and cons of each one for the purpose of forthcoming Latexing.

Comment: 1) Within a table environment, I didn't succeed in centring, that'all.*Added:*  Finally, I succeeded in using the table environment, but it must be in the `main` document, see my updated answer. `captionof`  is used when you want a caption of a certain type of float, without floating. I suppressed minipages because it's mandatory to know their widths, which you have to find by trials and errors; my solution doesn't require such computations. As to `\hline`s, there's often a problem in LaTeX, contents of cells that touch the line. `Booktabs` offers a better vertical (customisable) spacing.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks for your rigorous answer, I learned a lot from you!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, \newsavebox wastes both a count register and a box register.  So to not waste registers you can use:

```
%to be input
\bgroup% save all registers to stack
\countdef\independent=1\relax% count register
\independent=0\relax% box register
\begin{lrbox}{\independent}
  $ \begin{aligned}
  P_f &= \Bigl(∑_{i=1}ⁿ P_i⁻¹\Bigr)⁻¹ \\
  \hat{x}_f &= P_f \Bigl (∑_{i=1}ⁿ P_i⁻¹ \hat{x}_i\Bigr)
  \end{aligned}
  $
\end{lrbox}

\countdef\correlated=2\relax% count register
\correlated=1\relax% box register
\begin{lrbox}{\correlated}
  $ \begin{aligned}
  P_f &= (e^T Σ^{-1} e)⁻¹ \\
  \hat{x}_f &= P_f (e^T Σ^{-1} \hat{x})
  \end{aligned}
  $
\end{lrbox}
\countdef\uc=2\relax% count register
\uc=1\relax% box register
\begin{lrbox}{\uc}
  $ \begin{aligned}
  P_f &= \Bigl(∑_{i=1}ⁿ ω_i P_i⁻¹\Bigr)⁻¹ \\
  \hat{x}_f &= P_f \Bigl (∑_{i=1}ⁿ ω_i P_i⁻¹ \hat{x}_i\Bigr)
  \end{aligned} $
\end{lrbox}


  \setlength\aboverulesep{0.65ex}
  \setlength\belowrulesep{0.9ex}
  \captionsetup{position =above}

  \caption{Multi-sensor Fusion Rules}
  \begin{threeparttable}
    \begin{tabular}{cc@{\qquad}c}
      Types of Estimation Errors & Fusion Rules & Comments \\
      \midrule\midrule
      \makecell{No Correlations \\(Independent)} & \usebox{\independent} & Optimal \\
      \cmidrule(l r){1-3}
      \makecell{Known Correlations \\ (Correlated)} & \usebox{\correlated} \tnote{*} & Optimal \\
      \cmidrule(l r){1-3}
      Unknown Correlations & \usebox{\uc} \tnote{**} & \makecell{Suboptimal } \\
      \midrule\midrule
    \end{tabular}
    \vskip 0.8ex
    \begin{tablenotes}
      \item[*] $e=[I, ⋯ , I]^T$, $\Sigma=(P_{ij}), \; i,j=1, ⋯ , n$, and $\hat{x}= [\hat{x}_1^T, ⋯ , \hat{x}_n^T]^T$.\vskip 1.2ex
      \item[**] Covariance intersection rule, where $ω_i ∈ [0\,,1],\; ∑_{i=1}^n ω_i=1$, and $ω_i=\arg\min_{ω_i\in[0\,,1]} \text{tr}\{P_{f}\}$.
    \end{tablenotes}
  \end{threeparttable}
\egroup% restore registers
```

You might also look at [Reusing saveboxes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185140/reusing-saveboxes)
or you can just load the etex package and waste registers without a care.