# Breaking page in `subfigure` environment

Tags: graphics, page-breaking

I have four images and want to put them in one figure so that two images per page. I used `subfigure` environment, the problem is the first two images are shown and the other are not.

How can I break the page when using `subfigure` environment?

And if I want to put some text between these subfigures how can I do that?

Comment: Maybe use TWO subfigure enviroments (2x2).

Comment: You can't have a float bigger than one page.  The subfigures you can't see are running off the bottom of the paper.  You need to use two figures, 2 subfigures per figure.  If there is room below the first figure, ordinary text will fit there.

Comment: You might find http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280998/figure-on-an-even-page-and-caption-on-the-following-page useful.