# Too many columns in table leading to overflow of text

Tags: tables, columns

I have to make a table of size 3x23, with each column heading having at least 3 characters in it and maximum 10 characters in it. using `\tiny` on the heading names makes the heading too small to read. Is there any other alternative to this?

```
\begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | l | }
\hline
    Method & plane & bike & bird & boat & bottle & bus & car & cat & chair & cow & table & dog & horse & motor & person & plant & sheep & sofa & train & tv & mAP \\ \hline
    CNN-RNN & 96.7 & 83.1 & 94.2 & 92.8 & 61.2 & 82.1 & 89.1 & 94.2 & 64.2 & 83.6 & 70 & 92.4 & 91.7 & 84.2 & 93.7 & 59.8 & 93.2 & 75.3 & 99.7 & 78.6 & 84 \\ \hline
    Our Method & 93.5 & 84.7 & 90.6 & 87.8 & 43 & 83 & 89.3 & 87 & 55.1 & 74.7 & 68.7 & 87.5 & 88.8 & 85.7 & 92.3 & 50.6 & 75 & 57.1 & 95.1 & 68.9 & 77 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: is that really the only way to display the information, how do you expect your readers to read it? without any subject knowledge and with no example shown, no one can suggest any alternative layout so your question is not answerable in its current form.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Would it help you to print the table in landscape, for example by using the `landscape environment of the `lscape` package, or the `sidewaystable` of the `rotating` package?

Comment: A `\resizebox` can give good results for tables. With an MWE we can give you a more informed solution.

Comment: Reorganize table into two narrowed ones or transpose it or see if rotating table to landscape orientation is acceptable. Use of `\resizebox` is desperate try of last resort ...

Comment: You you are using a twoside layout, it is possible to force two tabulars to appear on consecutive even-odd pages.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280998/figure-on-an-even-page-and-caption-on-the-following-page/281075?s=4|0.8031#281075 for a similar example.