# Make LaTeX produce pages in a spreadsheet of two pages instead of one

Tags: books

I am starting from this code :

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=142mm, paperheight=210mm,top=25mm, bottom=20mm, left=17mm, right=22mm]{geometry}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}    
\chapter*{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-3]
\chapter{First chapter}
\lipsum[3-6]
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\lipsum[6-9]
\end{document}
```

Which produces one page at a time. What I need is a spreadsheet of two pages for the book printer. I suspect it is an option for the `\documentclass{book}`.

The result should look like this :
[image]

Comment: No, there is no book option for this. You can create such spreadsheets with pdfpages, but normally the book printer should be quite able to do it from the pdf.

Comment: If you intend to spread across and even-odd page pair, there are ways to do that using afterpage.  The big problem is how to split it into two tabulars with a gap in the middle.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280998/figure-on-an-even-page-and-caption-on-the-following-page

Comment: As Ulrike said, the `pdfpages` package can do it. However, I suspect that the printer also wants some crop marks etc., and furthermore that the two pages that should go onto the same sheet are not contiguous. This is something to worry about at the very end, when the exact number of pages etc. is known. You can assume there are ways to do it; while you are still writing and proofreading the book, it is much better to stick with the regular single page format.

Comment: He showed me an example and the pages can be contiguous. Crop margins will have to be added later because I dont know them yet. I will try insisting with him on why he cant use the single page format though.

Comment: yo' suggested `\usepackage{pgfpages}
\pgfpagesuselayout{2 on 1}[letterpaper,landscape]`. It works fine, but I cant set the page dimensions I want on the spread (height, double width of logical page). I will post it as the solution if nothing else comes out. Meanwhile the printer guy seems to be accepting single pages.