# Caption to 2-side image

Tags: floats

I need to add a caption to my 2-side image. I decide to using for that free space in foot page. I am  using dpfloat, xargs, and fancyhdr pachages:

```
\newcommandx{\twosidepic}[2][2]{
\thispagestyle{alim}
    \begingroup
    \sbox0{\includegraphics{#1}}
    \tmp{#2}\thispagestyle{capt}
    \begin{figure}[p]% will be the left-side figure
    \begin{leftfullpage}
    \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[trim=0 0 {.5\wd0} 0,width=\dimexpr\paperwidth-0.75in\relax,clip]{#1}}
    \end{leftfullpage}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[p]
    \begin{fullpage}
    \noindent\makebox[\textwidth]{\includegraphics[trim={.5\wd0} 0 0 0,width=\dimexpr\paperwidth-0.75in\relax,clip]{#1}}
    \end{fullpage}
    \end{figure}
    \endgroup
}

 \fancypagestyle{alim}{\fancyhf{}\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}\fancyfoot[C]{eeeeee}}
```

Problem is that thispagestyle applyed to else pages, not to page I need. How to add a caption?

Answer (score 1):

Solved!

I add caption not on foot page, but just as normal caption. If anybody know how to ajust foot page, feel free to share it :)

```
\newcommandx{\twosidepic}[2][2]{
    \begingroup
    \sbox0{\includegraphics{#1}}
    %\tmp{#2}\thispagestyle{capt}
    \begin{figure}[p]% will be the left-side figure
    \begin{leftfullpage}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
    \hspace*{-\leftmargin}
    \includegraphics[trim=0 0 {.5\wd0} 0,width=\dimexpr\paperwidth-0.75in\relax,clip]{#1}
    \captionsetup{font = Large, labelfont=Large, singlelinecheck = false, format= hang, justification=raggedleft, labelsep=space}
    \caption*{}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{leftfullpage}
    \end{figure}
    \begin{figure}[p]
    \begin{fullpage}
    \noindent\begin{minipage}[t][\textheight][c]{\textwidth}
    \hspace*{-\leftmargin}
    \includegraphics[trim={.5\wd0} 0 0 0,width=\dimexpr\paperwidth-0.75in\relax,clip]{#1}
    \captionsetup{font = Large, labelfont=Large, singlelinecheck = false, format= hang, justification=raggedleft, labelsep=space}
    \caption*{#2}
    \end{minipage}
    \end{fullpage}
    \end{figure}
    \endgroup
}
```

Comment: Just add a lot of negative \vspace inside the figure (just as fullpage adds a lot of negavtive \hspace to the sides).  BTW, the amount of space at the bottom of the page is `{\dimexpr \paperheight-1in-\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-\textheight}`.

Comment: BTW, you can use an \afterpage loop (afterpage package) to wait for the next even page.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280998/figure-on-an-even-page-and-caption-on-the-following-page/281075?r=SearchResults&s=9|23.4374#281075

Comment: Thank you for your attention!