# in twoside: arrange two figures on one double page, one on the left page. one on the right - images on facing pages

Tags: floats, double-sided, page, sidebyside

I try to force the auto layout process of LaTex to bring one image on the left page of a double side (twoside) formatted document and the corresponding second one on the right page.

According to the details in each picture and the length of the caption, each picture is enough to fill a whole page.

I have several sets of those 2 pictures to be set in one subsection containing only about one page of text.

Any ideas how to tell LaTex do the placement and arrange the text maybe including other (sub)sections around?

The base structure for bringing both pitures after each other I use is:

```
\begin{figure}[ph]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=0.82\linewidth]{Name_left_page_picture}
  \caption{Left paged figure's caption containing 5 lines of text.
    }
  \label{abb:left-paged-figure}
\end{figure} 
\begin{figure}[ph]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{right-paged-image}
  \caption{ Right paged figure's caption containing 7 lines of text.
    }
  \label{abb:right-paged-figure}
\end{figure}
```

but it isn't able to define the page each figure appears.

**EDIT**:

Here a symbolic how it should look like:
Both mages couples are associated with subsection 1 and have separate captions.

[image: Double sided pictures in context of a chapter]

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280998/figure-on-an-even-page-and-caption-on-the-following-page  It's actually two figures, only one has nothing but a caption in it.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that your first image is put on a verso (even-numbered) page.

The `memoir` (a superset of `book` and `report`) class has several commands in addition to the standard `\clearpage` and `\cleardoublepage` for going on to odd or even numbered pages. If you are not using `memoir` then the following is the code for its moving onwards.

```
% memmacros.tex

% \cleartoevenpage[<text>]
% clear to the next even numbered page, putting the optional <text> on the 
% skipped page, if any
\newcommand{\cleartoevenpage}[1][\@empty]{%
  \clearpage
  \ifodd\c@page\hbox{}#1\clearpage\fi}

% \movetoevenpage[<text>]
% move to the next even numbered page without flushing floats, putting the
% optional <text> on the skipped page, if any

% \cleartooddpage[<text>]
% like \cleartoevenpage but goes to next odd page
\newcommand{\cleartooddpage}[1][\@empty]{%
  \newpage%
  \ifodd\c@page\else\hbox{}#1\clearpage\fi}

% \movetooddpage[<text>]
% like \movetoevenpage but goes to next odd page
\newcommand{\movetooddpage}[1][\@empty]{%
  \newpage%
  \ifodd\c@page\else\hbox{}#1\clearpage\fi}
```

How you might use these is up to how you want your document to look but it's basically:

```
% some stuff
\cleartoevenpage
\begin{figure}[ph]
% and so on
```

Comment: Thanks for the hits. I tried to integrate that. The principle is doing, what was asked, but the pictures are flushed to the end of the chapter.
Any further ideas?

Comment: @Henning Try changing the optional location argument from `[ph]` to `[p]`.

Comment: It seems removing the `h` forces a better behavior but the page before the first figure the spaces between the paragraphs are stretched to several centimeters.

Comment: I have to use `\cleartooddpage` to get the desired behavior. As I integrate that command I get 4 error messages related to the line of the first `begin{figure}` directly after the command: `Missing number, treated as zero. \begin`; `You can't use \`\spacefactor' in vertical mode. \begin` and twice: `Missing $ inserted. \begin.` (caption contains math mode terms) without any of the newly defined commands no error occurs.