# Two figures on opposite pages sharing the same caption

Tags: captions, includegraphics

I am trying to divide one large figure into two pages and add a shared caption that starts on the left side and continues on the right side. I have attached a figure below that illustrates what I want it to look like. Do some of you have a solution to this problem, or some tips on how to achieve this layout?
[image: Ilustration]

A segment of my code is shown under

```
\documentclass[12pt,b5paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}  
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\section{Headline}
\lipsum[2-8]

\afterpage{%
    \clearpage% flush all other floats
    \ifodd\value{page}
    %\else% uncomment this else to get odd/even instead of even/odd
        \expandafter\afterpage% put it on the next page if this one is odd
    \fi
    {%
    \begin{figure}[p]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.9\textheight]{example-image-a}
        \caption{This caption should break apart and continue under the figure on the next page. 
        \\ \\ \lipsum[5]}
        \label{fig:example-image-a}
    \end{figure}
    \clearpage
    \begin{figure}[p]
        \centering
        \includegraphics[width=\textwidth,height=0.9\textheight]{example-image-b}
        \label{fig:example-image-b}
    \end{figure}
    \clearpage
    }%
}

\lipsum[2-7]

\end{document}
```

which yields the following two-paged output
[image: Screenshot of output from Latex code]

Comment: That is possible but could you edit into your question a [Minimal Working Example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) please? It's so that people can see how your compiling/creating this document, it is easier to help if so, this question might get closed as there is no latex code in it to edit/change to achieve your solution

Comment: You can use example-image or variants or even \rule.  I believe captions are unbreakable, so you would have to manually break the contents.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280998/figure-on-an-even-page-and-caption-on-the-following-page/281075?r=SearchResults&s=3%7C30.0964#281075

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX StackExchange. Please include always the MWE of the problem in your question, with all the code that we should know to understand where you are stacked, but only the code related to the issue, plus the minimal document structure to make it reproducible "as is", just this MWE one possible solution:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum} %just for make dummy text
\usepackage{dpfloat,graphicx} % needed for the solution
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10] % Dummy text
\begin{figure}[p]% will be the left-side figure
\begin{leftfullpage}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, trim=0pt 0pt 5.5cm 0pt,clip]{example-image}
\caption{\lipsum[1][1]\ldots}
\end{leftfullpage}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]% will be the right-side figure
\begin{fullpage}
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth, trim=5.5cm 0pt 0pt 0pt,clip]{example-image}
\vspace{\abovecaptionskip}\ldots\lipsum[1][3]
\end{fullpage}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[11-40] % Dummy text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this solution! It is exactly what I was looking for. I will look through the MWE by next time

Comment: @VSPZ The custom here is thank the good answers (and questions) by up voting the good answers (clicking on the upper triangle at the left)  and wen you asked the question, also accepting the answer that that best solved your problem  (clicking the check mark). For instance, I have already thanked you in that way for edit  the question to include a MWE.