# How do I get the caption alone on the page preceding the figure?

Tags: vertical-alignment, alignment

I'm desperately trying to complete my dissertation and one of the requirements is to have the caption alone on the page preceding the figure, without any other text. I am currently using `fltpage` to get the caption on the previous page but it only places it with other text. Any suggestions welcome!

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.  Could you please provide a small compilable example that shows what you are doing now, starting with the `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`.  Include only relevant packages, a small amount of text (it can be dummy text), a "canned" test figure, and its caption.  Then a potential helper can experiment without having to guess.  (Our crystal balls are rather ineffective.)

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280998/figure-on-an-even-page-and-caption-on-the-following-page

Comment: Any news? Does any of received answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

As you are not providing clear `MWE`, I understood that your image occupies full page and you need to place its caption on the next page without any text, if I'm correct, you can try with:

```
\begin{figure}[p]
includegraphics{...}
\end{figure}

\begin{figure}[p]
\caption{...}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: No. The questioner asked for the caption to be on the page *before* not after the figure.

Answer (score 1):

- Your question is unclear, so answer is based on guessing, how should your requirements looks ...
- Your strange requirement has some sense, if the caption is on odd page and figure on the even ...

```
\documentclass{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}% For dummy text. Don't use in a real document
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-3]
\clearpage
\mbox{}
\vfil   % where on page should be, for at bottom use \vfill
\captionof{figure}{My caption is alone on page}
\clearpage
\mbox{}
\vfil   % where on page should be, for at bottom use \vfill
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image-duck}
\clearpage
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]