# Combine the H and p options for a figure environment?

Tags: figure-placement, dpfloat

Is there a way to combine the `H` and `p` options for a `figure` environment? I am using the `dpfloat` package in order to guarantee that certain pairs of figures occur on facing pages; and the `dpfloat` documentation (https://mirrors.mit.edu/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/dpfloat/dpfloat.pdf) tells us to use the `p` option. However, while requiring certain pairs of pages to be facing, and thus the `p` option, I also require the figures to occur at a specific point in the text, and thus I require the `H` option or equivalent.

(I am using XeLaTeX.)

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperwidth=4.25in, paperheight=5.5in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath, mathtools}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[strict]{changepage}
\usepackage{dpfloat}

\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\setlength{\headheight}{25.1pt}

\fancyhf{}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\iffloatpage{}{\thepage \hspace{1cm} \leftmark}}
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\iffloatpage{}{\leftmark \hspace{1cm} \thepage}}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
{\normalfont\fillast}
{{\Huge \thechapter}}
{1ex minus .1ex}
{\large \thispagestyle{empty}}
\titlespacing{\chapter}
{3pc}{*3}{*2}[3pc]

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter}

Words I wish to have precede the pair of facing pages

\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{leftfullpage}
\newgeometry{top=5mm,bottom=0cm}
\begin{adjustwidth}{-1.5cm}{-1.5cm}
\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=3.5in]{plate I.jpg}
\end{center}
\end{adjustwidth}
\restoregeometry
\end{leftfullpage}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[p]
\begin{fullpage}
\begin{center}
Caption of image on facing page
\end{center}
\end{fullpage}
\end{figure}

Words I wish to have follow the pair of facing pages at the beginning of a new page

\end{document}
```

Here is my image, in case it matters:
[image]

Comment: If you really want to fix the position of the pictures, then don't put them in a floating environment like `figure` -- just use `includegraphics` where you want it.  And use the `captionof` package if you need to add a caption that fits in with your other captions.

Comment: A large [p] float (height > \floatpagefraction\textheight) will appear on the next page if the queue is empty.  With dpfloat, that would be the next even page instead.  Another trick is to use \afterpage (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280998/figure-on-an-even-page-and-caption-on-the-following-page).

Comment: you can simply use `\newpage \begin{figure}[H] ...\end{figure} \newpage` if you want a H-figure to appear on a page of its own.

Comment: You cannot combine contradictory options as stay [H]ere and move to a [p]age of floats, the same that you have the option to sleep or be awake but not both at the same time. Is just impossible. If you want a couple of images aligned side by side with text, use [t], placing the first float  between the text of a even page and the second  far enough to be load in the next  page, not before, nor after. If there are previous floats,  be sure that they can be placed before of that pages.