# How include full page figures on left page with figure legend on right

Tags: floats, thesis

I'm writing a thesis and most of my figures are already made and referenced in the text. The figures are almost all full pages, and the figure legends are also long.

I'm hoping there is an easy way to enforce having the figure be on the left page and the figure caption/description on the right page. Something like below, where pic is the actual graphic and desc is the caption/description

```
 ------- ------
|       |      |
|   pic | desc |
|       |      |
|       |      |
 ------- ------
```

Currently, each figure is encoded using the following template

```
\begin{figure}[p]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{1_figures-and-files/1.png}
    \caption[Caption.]{\textbf{Caption.} (A) panel A, (B), panel b, etc}
    \label{fig 1-1}
\end{figure}
```

I've perused other similar posts but couldn't find anything that matches. Sorry if i missed it

Thanks!
Joe

Comment: Welcome here! You don't provide a minimal working example an so we don't know which documentclass you use. For example, the KOMAscript classes offer descriptions beside the figure. And then there is the caption package, you get, as always, the manual with `texdoc caption` ('texdoc packagename') on the command line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/280998/figure-on-an-even-page-and-caption-on-the-following-page