# How to delete a counter?

Tags: counters, package-writing, definition

I am trying to delete a counter in my ".sty" file. Right now I have a few ".tex" files that use the same ".sty". They use the same ".sty" file to use `\newcommands`. However, when I go to make a new counter sometimes the counter may have the same name. When that is the case I get a compiler error since I'm trying to create something that is already defined. Is there a way I can delete the counter?

An example of what is happening in my code can be seen below:

```
\newcommand{\addMsg}[1] % This would be in the file.sty
{
    \newcounter{#1}
}

\addMsg{nameOfCounter}  % This would be in File1.tex
\addMsg{nameOfCounter}  % This would be in File1.tex
```

Keep in mind many people may edit these files, thus in `file1.tex` someone may put `\addMsg{Counter1}` and in `file2.tex` someone may also put `\addMsg{Counter1}`. Thus I cannot just simply make sure all counters are named differently.

Comment: Probably you should be clearer about *how* you want to use these counters. Surely, having the same counter used for different purposes is a recipe for disaster.

Answer (score 5):

You can't un-define a counter. You could overwrite its definition, but then you would waste counter memory (not a problem, nowadays, but. . .), or you'd need to mess with their lower level implementation. Much easier is to define a `\providecounter` macro which only defines a counter if it doesn't yet exist:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\providecounter#1{%
  \@ifundefined{c@#1}%
    {\newcounter{#1}}{\@newctr}}
\makeatother

\providecounter{mycounter}
\providecounter{mycounter}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This should IMHO be a standard LaTeX command. +1

Comment: This is helpful although im still not sure it helps my exact situation i think i may have an idea now that u gave me this idea.

Comment: @JacobHacker You can, of course, redefine LaTeX's `\newcounter` to behave like that, if the name of the command is the problem, although I recommend you not to do that...

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat - Having more than one package using the same counter for different purposes is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: @JohnKormylo Well, many counters are just dummy counters, I often introduce `iloop` for `\loop`s, so I'm really glad to see that there is a simple way to define it without getting all the complaints that there is an error. Sure, if you have nothing better to do than calling your "new" counter `equation`, say, then you are crying for trouble.

Comment: im using counters to store number values and to refer to them at a later time would using \chardef be better for what i am doing, because i dont even need the functionality of the counter.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185140/reusing-saveboxes/185152?r=SearchResults&s=1|21.2906#185152

Comment: @JacobHacker It's not really a good idea to use `\chardef`'ed counters as you could, for example, do `\chardef\mycount=31`, and then you'd overwrite the `equation` counter (in my version of LaTeX; the exact number may vary depending on your version). It's better to use `\newcount\mycount`, then the number is automatically assigned (with `\chardef`). You would fall into the memory waste, if many packages did `\newcount\mycount`, but no error... Either way, the point raised in John Kormylo's first commend would be valid...