# How to create numbered-named saveboxes in a foreach-loop?

Tags: boxes, foreach, box

[image]

Is there a principally way to create numbered saveboxes?
For a usage like: `\usebox{box-1}, \usebox{box-2}, \usebox{box-3}`

The follwing MWE gives no error, but no output. 
PS: It seems to be clear why this can't work. So the question is, how to make it work (in contrast to further error analysis).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {1,2,3}{
\expandafter\newsavebox\csname box-\n\endcsname
\expandafter\savebox\csname box-\n\endcsname{The content No. \n}
}
Test: \expandafter\usebox\csname box-3\endcsname
\end{document}
```

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/185140/reusing-saveboxes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try `xsavebox` which makes use of PDF XObjects to store the contents only once in the PDF. Also, boxes do not need be declared and have global scope:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xsavebox}

\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {1,2,3}{
  \xsbox{box-\n}{The content No. \n}
}  
Test: \xusebox{box-3}
\end{document}
```

Alternatively, an `expl3` approach that saves the content in TeX boxes with global scope:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% \sboxx{<box name>}{<content>}
% \useboxx{<box name>}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\sboxx}{mm}{
  \box_clear_new:c{cis-box-#1}\hbox_gset:cn{cis-box-#1}{#2}
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\useboxx}{m}{\box_use:c{cis-box-#1}}
\ExplSyntaxOff
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}
\foreach \n in {1,2,3}{
  \sboxx{box-\n}{The content No. \n}
}%  
Test: \useboxx{box-3}

\foreach \n in {1,2,3}{ % Re-use existing boxes
  \sboxx{box-\n}{The content No. \n a}
}%  
Test: \useboxx{box-3}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

The `pgf` command `\foreach` forms a group, so you loose all of the definitions at the end of the loop. I'd use the `expl3` function `\int_step_inline:nnnn` here, wrapped up in a document command

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \ForEach { O { 1 } m O { 1 } +m }
  { \int_step_inline:nnnn {#1} {#3} {#2} {#4} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\ForEach{3}{
\expandafter\newsavebox\csname box-#1\endcsname
\expandafter\savebox\csname box-#1\endcsname{The content No. #1}
}
Test: \expandafter\usebox\csname box-1\endcsname
\end{document}
```

With the argument specification given, we can give the starting value as a first optional argument, and the step size as an optional argument between the two mandatory ones.

Answer (score 1):

Following on from other answers, the `:c` argument signature seems to work OK, so everything could be done fully in expl3:

[image: box98]

including a user box-access function (`\myboxnum` in the example) using the number (say) or some other arbitrary string.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins,xparse}
\tcbuselibrary{listings}
\DeclareTCBListing{mybox}{ s O{} m }{%
colback=red!3!white,
colframe=red!75!blue,
fonttitle=\sffamily\bfseries,
bicolor,
colbacklower=yellow!20,
segmentation style={double=white,draw=blue,
double distance=1pt,solid},
listing options={style=tcblatex,numbers=left,numberstyle=\small\color{blue!75!black},numbersep=5pt},
title=\getegcounter\ -- #3,#2}



\ExplSyntaxOn
%==============================
\newcounter{ic_eg_count}[section]
\cs_new:Nn \ic_get_egnum: {
\refstepcounter{ic_eg_count}[\thesection.\theic_eg_count]
}

\cs_set_eq:NN \getegcounter \ic_get_egnum:
\ExplSyntaxOff


%========================================
\begin{document}

\section{Test}


%===================== 
\begin{mybox}{Box 4}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \box_new:N { c }
\cs_set:Npn \ic_funcpp:n #1 { \box_new:c { l_myicppz#1_box }
 \hbox_set:cn { l_myicppz#1_box } { Contents ~ #1 }
 x\box_use:c { l_myicppz#1_box }y ~ : ~
 \box_show:c { l_myicppz#1_box }
}
\cs_set:Nn \ic_funcppb:  {
\int_step_function:nnnN { 97 } { 1 } { 99 } \ic_funcpp:n
}
\NewDocumentCommand { \mycmdppb } { } { \ic_funcppb: }
%
\cs_set:Npn \ic_funcpq:n #1 { \box_use:c { l_myicppz#1_box } }
\NewDocumentCommand { \myboxnum } { m } {  \box_use:c { l_myicppz#1_box } }
\ExplSyntaxOff
  \mycmdppb
  \par >>\myboxnum{98}<<
\end{mybox}
\bigskip





\end{document}
```

Comment: `\box_new:c` variant already exists in the format.

Comment: @AlexG Thanks. Yes, line 2 can be commented out; it is superfluous.